# How do I implement Python outputs straight into a website automatically using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm currently trying to get separate lists of prices to upload straight to my website: virtualcoincomparison.com
How do I do this? Is this even possible using Beautiful Soup? I'm new to python and Beautiful Soup so i'm not sure

Comment: First show us want you tried. Second BeautyfulSoup is meant to scrap website, is that what you want?

Comment: I have made the scraper but would like to know how I can run the program in python and then the outputs automatically get uploaded to the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you could do this:

- use SFTP or WebDAV to upload data files
- create an admin page on your site (allow it to pull from your computer)
- create an API, then use the API to submit the data
- set up a timed script, so your site does the scraping on its own
- ?? probably about 30 other ways